Segmentation faults on Ubuntu 22.04
I am experiencing segmentation faults on Ubuntu 22.04 and wanted to ask for help debugging.
I got some running sudo apt-get update: Segmentation faultsts... 52%
Running the software updater I get: update-manager crashed with SIGSEV
Another instance was a removing a conda environment.
Sometimes running python scripts in spyder:
/home/max/anaconda3/envs/spyder-env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/spyder/plugins/ipythonconsole/scripts/conda-activate.sh: line 18: 1216748 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) $CONDA_ENV_PYTHON -m spyder_kernels.console -f $SPYDER_KERNEL_SPEC


Fatal Python error: Segmentation fault


Main thread:
Current thread 0x00007bc69791f440 (most recent call first):
  File "/media/max/Workspace/Code/attention_states/tests/../src/temporal_response_function.py", line 55 in trf_train
  File "/media/max/Workspace/Code/attention_states/tests/../src/temporal_response_function.py", line 135 in trf_cross_val
  File "/media/max/Workspace/Code/attention_states/tests/../src/utils.py", line 128 in trf_region
  File "<stdin>", line 1 in <module>
  File "/home/max/anaconda3/envs/attention_states/lib/python3.13/site-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spyderpdb.py", line 268 in default
  File "/home/max/anaconda3/envs/attention_states/lib/python3.13/cmd.py", line 214 in onecmd
  File "/home/max/anaconda3/envs/attention_states/lib/python3.13/pdb.py", line 853 in onecmd
  File "/home/max/anaconda3/envs/attention_states/lib/python3.13/site-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spyderpdb.py", line 683 in cmdloop
  File "/home/max/anaconda3/envs/attention_states/lib/python3.13/site-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spyderpdb.py", line 653 in _cmdloop
  File "/home/max/anaconda3/envs/attention_states/lib/python3.13/site-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spyderpdb.py", line 333 in interaction
  File "/home/max/anaconda3/envs/attention_states/lib/python3.13/pdb.py", line 437 in user_line
  File "/home/max/anaconda3/envs/attention_states/lib/python3.13/bdb.py", line 122 in dispatch_line
  File "/home/max/anaconda3/envs/attention_states/lib/python3.13/bdb.py", line 96 in trace_dispatch
  File "/media/max/Workspace/Code/attention_states/tests/global_signal_phonemes_all.py", line 327 in <module>
  File "/home/max/anaconda3/envs/attention_states/lib/python3.13/bdb.py", line 651 in run
  File "/home/max/anaconda3/envs/attention_states/lib/python3.13/site-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spyderpdb.py", line 900 in run
  File "/home/max/anaconda3/envs/attention_states/lib/python3.13/site-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py", line 473 in exec_code
  File "/home/max/anaconda3/envs/attention_states/lib/python3.13/site-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py", line 615 in _exec_file
  File "/home/max/anaconda3/envs/attention_states/lib/python3.13/site-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py", line 660 in debugfile
  File "/tmp/ipykernel_1216748/3781023966.py", line 1 in <module>


Restarting kernel...

In addition other programs, such as visual studio or google chrome crash without errors.
I tried:

Reinstalled spyder
Created a new conda environment reinstalling all packages I used.
Ran conda clean -a
Run update and upgrade with apt-get
Ran memtest, which passed without errors
Stresstest the CPU
Try to fix broken packages in recovery mode, which resulted in a Segmentation fault.
Update the BIOS
Upgrade to Ubuntu 24.04

Here is an excerpt from a log (journalctl) that just came up after a segmentation fault when removing a conda environment:

59 ip 000000000056e762 sp 00007ffe27297e60 error 6 in
python3.10[41f000+1fb000] likely on CPU 4 (core 8, socket 0) 
Dec 02 > 16:13:52 max-workstation kernel:  
Code: 38 49 c7 44 24 48 00 00 00 00 48 85 ff 0f 85
9b 00 00 00 48 85 d2 0f 85 de 00 00 00 4d 85 ff 0f 85
bf 00 00 00 49 8b 4c 24 10 <48> c7 41 > 


Does anyone have suggestions on how to find the root of this issue? I could reinstall Ubuntu as well, but I would like to understand what's going on.

Welcome to ASK. Append to your question the result of the command line 'journalctl --since "2024-12-02 00:00" --until "2024-12-02 00:30" -k' (Adjust the start and finish time to pick an appropriate time to give a shortish result when you have actually seen the problem. If that doesn't show anything try it without the '-k'

Thanks for the response! I'm not familiar with these logs and not sure what to look for. I added some errors since the latest startup, some related to NVIDIA drivers, that do seem to be working otherwise though. Not entirely sure about the meaning of others. Does anything jump out?

Actually here is one that just came up after a segmentation fault when removing a conda environment: Dec 02 16:13:52 max-workstation kernel: conda[27217]: segfault at 59 ip 000000000056e762 sp 00007ffe27297e60 error 6 in python3.10[41f000+1fb000] likely on CPU 4 (core 8, socket 0) Dec 02 16:13:52 max-workstation kernel: Code: 38 49 c7 44 24 48 00 00 00 00 48 85 ff 0f 85 9b 00 00 00 48 85 d2 0f 85 de 00 00 00 4d 85 ff 0f 85 bf 00 00 00 49 8b 4c 24 10 <48> c7 41 >

Perhaps a corrupted low-level library would do this; using a rescue disk, install and run debsums.  If you're lucky, it might already be installed.

Two things stand out. The NVIDIA driver is tanting the kernal &  'BUG: Bad page state in process apport  pfn' Speculatively, the secnond may be caused by the first and a memory page error is likely to cause problems. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2549214/interpreting-segfault-messages https://discussion.fedoraproject.org/t/nvidia-taints-kernel/78117/6 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63686694/linux-kernel-bug-bad-page-state-in-process-understanding My experience of tracking things through 'gdb' is that it rapidly becomes complicated and only really for the experienced

Thanks, I have since yesterday reinstalled Ubuntu on the machine. I am guessing this would solve the low-level library issue. I also haven't seen the NVIDIA bug in the logs anymore. However, trying to install anaconda, I got a segmentation fault in again, with a similar error in the log: ```Dec 03 13:19:18 max-workstation kernel: _conda[18264]: segfault at 18 ip 00007bd3bfdec14f sp 00007ffde3385f10 error 4 in libpython3.11.so.1.0[7bd3bfcf2000+24b000] likely on CPU 4 (core 8, socket 0)
Dec 03 13:19:18 max-workstation kernel: Code: ...


Thanks for the pointe to the system logs, this was a lot of help finding the issue!

ls -larth /var/crash/

It seems like this was an error with the CPU.
As suggested journalctl --since "10 minutes ago" -k showed errors for each segmentation fault. The errors were always pointing to the same CPU: CPU 4 (core 8, socket 0)
With lscpu --all --extended, I found that this corresponds to core 2 (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71122837/how-to-detect-e-cores-and-p-cores-in-linux-alder-lake-system).
I was then able to turn off this core in the BIOS.
For the CPU (13th Gen Intel Core i9-13900KF) core 2 corresponds to P-core 2. In the BIOS (Motherboard Asus ROG STRIX Z690-E GAMING WIFI), I changed:
Advanced -> CPU Configuaration -> Per P-Core Control -> Enabled
Then
Advanced -> CPU Configuaration -> P-Core 2 -> Disabled.
System is working without segmentation faults for now.
